# Creating load balancer in AWS using Chef provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to create a load balancer in AWS. I already have the machine created and the machine's node file is in my nodes folder. I keep getting an error asking me to enter the instance id of the machine. I thought the whole point of using chef provisioning was to be able to use the name of the machine to be able to use it and not have to use it's instance ID. My code is as follows:

```
require 'chef/provisioning'  # driver for creating machines

provisioner = get_setting("CHEF_PROFILE", "abcd-environments")

require "chef/provisioning/aws_driver"

with_driver "aws:abcd-environments"

load_balancer 'test-elb-from-prov' do

  driver "aws:abcd-environments"
  machines ['webappsadm001.da.abcd']
  load_balancer_options   availability_zones: ['us-east-1b'],
  listeners: [{
    # required
    protocol: :http,
    # required
    port: 80,
    instance_protocol: :http,
    # required
    instance_port: 10262,
    }],
  subnets: ['subnet-37ce3a1c'],

    health_check:
    [{
      target: "TCP:10262",
      interval: 30,
      timeout: 5,
      unhealthy_threshold: 2,
      healthy_threshold: 10
    }]

end
```

The log is as follows:

```
 ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'load_balancer[test-elb-from-prov]'
    ================================================================================

    AWS::Core::OptionGrammar::FormatError
    -------------------------------------
    expected string value for key instance_id of member 1 of option instances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. I created the machine using the aws fog driver through another cookbook.

Then I try to attach a load balancer to the machine. When it tries to look into the node's JSON file, it is not in the same format and it errors out.

I deleted the machine and ran the cookbook. This created the machine using aws driver and the load balancer was created and attached as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is an existing node in your nodes folder, what you should be able to do is define a resource for that existing machine, with action :nothing, and then refer to that.

So if the node name is 'myinstance', the recipe would look like:

```
machine 'myinstance' do
  action :nothing
end

load_balancer 'my_load_balancer' do
  machines ['myinstance']
end
```

Comment: Are you using chef-provisioning-aws 1.1.1?